# Python Pandas - Rearrange Table Data into 1 Line

Tags: python, pandas

We have this code that extracts data from an iframe (thanks Cody):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/store/feedback-score/1665279.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = soup.select_one("#detail-displayer").attrs["src"]

r = s.get(f"https:{iframe_src}")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for row in soup.select(".history-tb tr"):
    print("\t".join([e.text for e in row.select("th, td")]))
```

Returning this:

```
Feedback    1 Month 3 Months    6 Months
Positive (4-5 Stars)    154 562 1,550
Neutral (3 Stars)   8   19  65
Negative (1-2 Stars)    8   20  57
Positive feedback rate  95.1%   96.6%   96.5%
```

And we need this output, all in 1 line:

[image]

How do we do it?

Comment: sounds like a job for df.pivot

Comment: @Yuca Cool, thanks. Do you know how to turn that for loop into pandas first? I'm stuck there

Comment: sadly I don't have a lot of time on my hands to do the proper research, otherwise I would give you a better answer. Someone will come soon, I'm sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code that does the work.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)

url = "https://www.aliexpress.com/store/feedback-score/1665279.html"
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
iframe_src = soup.select_one("#detail-displayer").attrs["src"]

r = s.get(f"https:{iframe_src}")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
rows = []
for row in soup.select(".history-tb tr"):
    print("\t".join([e.text for e in row.select("th, td")]))
    rows.append([e.text for e in row.select("th, td")])
print

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    rows,
    columns=['Feedback', '1 Month', '3 Months', '6 Months'],
)

# remove first row with column names
df = df.iloc[1:]
df['Shop'] = url.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]

pivot = df.pivot(index='Shop', columns='Feedback')
pivot.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in pivot.columns.values]

column_mapping = dict(
    zip(pivot.columns.tolist(), [col[:12] for col in pivot.columns.tolist()]))
# column_mapping
# {'1 Month Negative (1-2 Stars)': '1 Month Nega',
#  '1 Month Neutral (3 Stars)': '1 Month Neut',
#  '1 Month Positive (4-5 Stars)': '1 Month Posi',
#  '1 Month Positive feedback rate': '1 Month Posi',
#  '3 Months Negative (1-2 Stars)': '3 Months Neg',
#  '3 Months Neutral (3 Stars)': '3 Months Neu',
#  '3 Months Positive (4-5 Stars)': '3 Months Pos',
#  '3 Months Positive feedback rate': '3 Months Pos',
#  '6 Months Negative (1-2 Stars)': '6 Months Neg',
#  '6 Months Neutral (3 Stars)': '6 Months Neu',
#  '6 Months Positive (4-5 Stars)': '6 Months Pos',
#  '6 Months Positive feedback rate': '6 Months Pos'}
pivot.columns = [column_mapping[col] for col in pivot.columns]

pivot.to_excel('Report.xlsx')
```

You may want to sort the `pivot.columns` manually since they are sorted alphabetically (`1 Month Negative (1-2 Stars)'` comes before `'1 Month Neutral (3 Stars)'`). With the mapping of the columns in place, you would just need to pick a proper name for each of them and then they will be mapped (so you do not have to reorder them every time you decided to switch the neutral and negative positions, for instance). This is thanks to the dictionary lookup.

Comment: Very cool @Alex Tereshenkov, thanks a ton. The orders can be managed later in Excel, so that's no problem. But the name of the store is important, as I want to run it through a list of urls. Do you know how to take the number from the original URL filename? IE: 1665279.html => 1665279

Comment: No problem, glad to help! I've extracted a `url` variable to then later split taking the html page name.

Comment: Regarding the columns, you could define the right order once in your Python script (by accessing `pivot.columns`, reordering manually and setting back) and then even do an easy mapping such as `col_mapping = {'1 Month Negative (1-2 Stars)': '1M Neg', '1 Month Neutral (3 Stars)': '1M Neu'}` to replace the columns before exporting to Excel, save you some manual work :)

Comment: I've added more code on column mapping - hope this will save you some time!

Comment: Awesome!! Works like a charm

Comment: Can you take a look at this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526851/python-beautifulsoup-scrape-multiple-web-pages-with-iframes-from-given-urls

Comment: @FrankC, sorry just opened the page and saw the answer was given, glad things are working out for you!

Answer (score 1):

just `set_index` and `unstack`:

df:

```
                 Feedback 1 Month 3 Months 6 Months    store
0    Positive (4-5 Stars)     154      562    1,550  1665279
1       Neutral (3 Stars)       8       19       65  1665279
2    Negative (1-2 Stars)       8       20       57  1665279
3  Positive feedback rate   95.1%    96.6%    96.5%  1665279
```

then:

```
df = df[~df['Feedback'].str.contains('Positive feedback rate')]
new = df.set_index(['store', 'Feedback']).unstack(level=1)
# use f-strings with list comprehension
new.columns = new.columns = [f'{x} {y[:3]}' for x,y in new.columns]
```

or you can use `pivot`:

```
df = df[~df['Feedback'].str.contains('Positive feedback rate')]
new = df.pivot('store', 'Feedback')
new.columns = new.columns = [f'{x} {y[:3]}' for x,y in new.columns]
```

performance is about the same between the two:

`unstack: 3.61 ms ± 186 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1000 loops each)`

`pivot: 3.59 ms ± 114 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 1000 loops each)`